# XML parser configured here does not prevent nor limit external entities resolution

Tags: java, fortify

When I run HP Fortify on this program:

```
    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(bos);
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer;
    try {
        transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(domSource, result);
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I obtain this error:

> XML parser configured in ItemServlet.java:92 does not prevent nor limit external entities resolution. This can expose the parser to an XML External Entities attack.

According to this [blog](https://blog.csnc.ch/2012/08/secure-xml-parser-configuration/), the following features should be set.

```
tf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
tf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
```

But the problem is that my `TransformerFactory` instance does not support this method.

Comment: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#jaxp-documentbuilderfactory-saxparserfactory-and-dom4j

Answer (score 0):

You have to find a different way to prevent your transformer from expanding any external entities that you don't need.
This may require hacking your transformer, rewriting it or even preprocessing your XML to detect entities and throw an exception.